# Automate Git deployment

Tags: git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I want to automate the process of deployment of my website in debug mode on a remote machine(**not** a virtual machine). Steps that I follow right now:

1. Push new code to Git repo.
2. Access the remote machine and pull the code from the repo.
3. Install the dependencies(npm dependencies).
4. Run the webUI using 'npm start'.
5. Mail the testers the IP address and the port number.

Although the last step is always the same IP and port, in future it might change.

I have written a shell script that does all the above-mentioned steps. But, I have to trigger that script manually. This is fine for a machine or two. However, since we are now having multiple machines where this needs to be done, I want to change the manual triggering of the script to auto trigger as soon as I push some code to git. I came across ci/cd and tried implementing it. I achieved success for virtual machines. However, I could not find any sources or documentation for how to do the same for a real machine.

Is there a  way to automate all these steps as soon as I push the code to Git?

Comment: What have you tried so far to automate this ?  

Your description looks a lot like the outline of a script. Have you tried writing these steps in a script ?

Comment: Yes... I have written a shell script that does all the above-mentioned steps. But, I have to trigger that script manually. This is fine for a machine or two. However, since we are now having multiple machines where this needs to be done, I want to change the manual triggering of the script to auto trigger as soon as I push some code to git. I came across ci/cd and tried implementing it. I achieved success for virtual machines. However, I could not find any sources or documentation for how to do the same for a real machine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+deploy+hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to use [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). See for example the `post-receive` hook.

**Sum-up :**

You need a self-hosted git repo (doesn't really work with Github).

You put a bash script in `.git/hooks`. When someone pushes to your repo, the script gets executed.

Comment: where will this post-receive script get executed? Here is my confusion: When I do a git push, all the changes along with this script gets pushed to the remote repo. Now, do I have to write a script in post-receive to ssh into the machine where I wish to deploy this code? Or the post-receive script in that destination machine will auto-detect this new push and start executing?

Comment: @samirkumar post-receive hook gets executed on the remote repo machine. SSH is a good idea to do the deploiment on the needed environment.